# Setting up Audit.EntityFramework.Core for basic auditing

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, audit.net

In .net core web app I was using `Audit.EntityFramework 16.1.1` with `.net core 3.1` to log changes for two purposes:

- logging changes for specific tables for history/security and
- logging all the changes into one table (which is periodically deleted by scheduled job), for some rudimentary forensics if needed.

Code used in `Startup.cs` is like this:

```
var currentUser = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ICurrentUser>();

Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseEntityFramework(ef => ef
        .AuditTypeMapper(t => typeof(AuditLog))
        .AuditEntityAction<AuditLog>((ev, entry, entity) =>
        {
            entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            entity.AuditData = entry.ToJson();
            entity.EntityType = entry.EntityType.Name;
            entity.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            entity.AuditUsername = currentUser.GetUsername();
            entity.AuditUserId = currentUser.GetUserId();
            entity.EntityId = entry.PrimaryKey.Count > 1 ?
                string.Join("|", entry.PrimaryKey.Select(pk => pk.Value)) :
                entry.PrimaryKey.First().Value.ToString();
            entity.Action = entry.Action;
        })
        .IgnoreMatchedProperties(true));

Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseEntityFramework(ef => ef
        .AuditTypeExplicitMapper(m => m
        .Map<Table1, Table1History>((table, tableHistory) =>
        {
            FillTableHistoryData(table, tableHistory);
        })
        .Map<Table2, Table2History>((otherTable, otherTableHistory) =>
        {
            FillOtherTableHistoryData(otherTable, otherTableHistory);
        })
```

After upgrading app to `.net core 6` and `Audit.EntityFramework` to `19.1.0` (or any newer version) this stopped working. Reverting back to `16.1.1.` throws `MethodNotFoundException` (for `GetTableName` method).

So, I would like to avoid some serious refactoring and make this work as it used to at the same time. Could someone with experience with this give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it used to work in the old version, but you shouldn't call
`.UseEntityFramework()` multiple times since it will override the settings each time.

One option is to use `.MapExplicit` within the `AuditTypeExplicitMapper` to handle the tables not included in the `.Map<>` calls.

For example:

```cs
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseEntityFramework(ef => ef
        .AuditTypeExplicitMapper(m => m
            .Map<Table1, Table1History>((table, tableHistory) =>
            {
                FillTableHistoryData(table, tableHistory);
            })
            .Map<Table2, Table2History>((otherTable, otherTableHistory) =>
            {
                FillOtherTableHistoryData(otherTable, otherTableHistory);
            })
            .MapExplicit<AuditLog>(entry => IsAnotherTable(entry), (entry, entity) =>
            {
                entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                entity.AuditData = entry.ToJson();
                entity.EntityType = entry.EntityType.Name;
                // ...
            }))
        .IgnoreMatchedProperties(true));
```

You need to specify which entities are going to be handled by the `.MapExplicit`, for example:

```cs
bool IsAnotherTable(EventEntry entry)
{
    return entry.GetEntry().Entity is not Table1 and not Table2;
}
```

Comment: this was exactly what I needed. It works as expected - both Table1, Table2 and others are tracked in their respective History tables and all those other tables grouped in AuditLog. 
v 22.0.0.

Comment: about that that it used to work.... that is maybe an overstatement. Things stopped working some time ago, so maybe we didn't noticed that first part is getting overwritten.